# What is the use of Flux Debug ? In code below what it checks for.?

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

########## DEBUG Mode ###########

if [ -z ${FLUX_DEBUG+x} ];
  then FLUX_DEBUG=0
  else FLUX_DEBUG=1
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

`FLUX_DEBUG` is just a variable, when not defined `${FLUX_DEBUG+x}` expands to empty string "" otherwise to `x`, note that it's slightly different from `${FLUX_DEBUG:+x}` which expands to empty string also if FLUX_DEBUG is set to empty string.

For example compare:

```
 unset FLUX_DEBUG
 echo ${FLUX_DEBUG+x}
 echo ${FLUX_DEBUG:+x}

 FLUX_DEBUG=
 echo ${FLUX_DEBUG+x}
 echo ${FLUX_DEBUG:+x}

 FLUX_DEBUG=value
 echo ${FLUX_DEBUG+x}
 echo ${FLUX_DEBUG:+x}
```

For more information [read bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)